# How to convert a string of numbers to a numeric type and return the sum of that number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with a couple of columns with vector values:

```
df['impulses'][1]
```

equals: `[0.79528845 0.09930359 0.00662024 0.03765798 0.00464277 0.05648697]'`

The problem is the datatype of those columns is string, and I need to sum each element inside the vector and return a single value column. In order to change their `str` value, I was trying `astype(int)` but got **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10.**

I also tried `pd.to_numeric` but again got **ValueError: Unable to parse string**

How can I sum all the elements as return as a single value?

Comment: You mean it is a space separated string value..?eg `["0.2344 0.672527 0.123344"]`

Comment: type `df['impulses'].head(5).to_dict()` and paste the values into your question

Comment: Then you should replace and split the data

Comment: Paste it as text not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in your comment above, you have an structure like this for every index:

`'[0.26784756 0.54303095 0.1700662 0.01592414 0.00125246 0.00187869]'`

And you want to build a float array from it. Try to do something like this for each index in the DataFrame

First remove the brackets from each string:

```
vector_string = '[0.26784756 0.54303095 0.1700662 0.01592414 0.00125246 0.00187869]'
rm_brackets = vector_string.strip('[').strip(']')
```

And then split the result and convert each element into `float` instead of `int`. This should work:

```
float_array = [float(i) for i in rm_brakets.split()]
```

Finally you can sum your `float_array` to get the desire result.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df['impulses_sum'] = df['impulses'].apply(lambda a: sum([float(x.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for x in a.split(' ')]))
```

Comment: Hi @Gustava, Thanks! I'm getting **TypeError: 'float' object is not callable** using the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get every items sum by:

```
import re
for i in range(0, len(df['impulses'])):
    _str = df.iloc[i]['impulses']
    Sum = sum([float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', _str)])
    print(Sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried. Getting this error: **TypeError: 'float' object is not callable**

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(["[0.2678476 0.54303095 0.1700662 0.01592414 0.00125246 0.00187869]", "[10 10 20 10]"], columns=["impulse"])
 print(df)
```

**OutPut**

```
    impulse
0   [0.2678476 0.54303095 0.1700662 0.01592414 0.0...
1   [10 10 20 10]
```

**Code**

```
 df['impulse'] =  df["impulse"].apply(lambda x: sum([float(a) for a in x.replace("[","").replace("]", "").split(" ")]))
 pritn(df)
```

**Output**

```
    impulse
 0  1.0
 1  50.0
```

Comment: I don't give down vote but I checked and it on a sample .csv file and does not works for it which first row is :a (column label), second row: [0.2 0.4 0.3].

Comment: I don't know why its not working on your test case.But it did work for me